# How to split this string a\r\b\r\c

Tags: python, pandas, list

How to split this string a\r\b\r\c
I want the result to be individual values like a b c.

Code which I am using is here. Its not removing \r\

```
device_list
for i in device_list:
list = i.split("\\r\\")
df = pd.DataFrame(device_list)
df
```

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `print(device_list)`

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in device_list:
    list = i.split("\r")
df = pd.DataFrame(device_list)
df
```

This should work. I believe you don't need to use an escape character in the split function because the function searches for that parameter in string 'i' and adds them to returned list when that parameter is found.

So, for your original code, split function is looking at string 'i' and whenever it finds/or would find the substring '//r//' then and only then it would add the element in the returning list.

PS. Try to not use words like 'list', 'dict', 'set' etc as variable names as they are already used by the python language.